# Recuperar valores desde 3 tablas

Tags: php, sql

Tengo tres tablas `servicios`, `usuarios` e `instaladores2`, como se muestran aquí:

```
usuarios                 servicios                      instaladores2
---------------          ---------------------          --------------
id_usuario               id_contrato                    id_instalador
nombre_completo          nombre_cliente                 nombre_completo
                         domicilio_instalacion 
                         colonia
                         poblacion
                         telefono_local
                         telefono_cel_1
                         telefono_cel_2
                         telefono_cel_3 
                         nombre_contacto
                         Comentario
                         hora_instalacion 
                         cita_confirmada
                         id_instalador
                         id_gestiono
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que me traiga el nombre de quién gestiono, de momento tengo el código así:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
                    `id_contrato`,
                    `nombre_cliente`,
                    `domicilio_instalacion`,
                    `colonia`,
                    `poblacion`,
                    `telefono_local`,
                    `telefono_cel_1`,
                    `telefono_cel_2`,
                    `telefono_cel_3`,
                    `nombre_contacto`,
                    `Comentario`,
                    ti.nombre_completo as instalador,
                    hora_instalacion,
                    cita_confirmada
                FROM 
                    `bd_servicios` as tc
                        inner join 
                    bd_instaladores2 as ti on (tc.id_instalador = ti.id_instalador)
                WHERE 
                    fecha_instalacion = '$fecha_instalacion'
                    $where
                ORDER BY 
                    instalador, hora_instalacion
                    ;";
```

Lo que hasta el momento hace este código que sí funciona, es una lista de los servicios y me jala el nombre del instalador de la tabla `instaladores2`, ya que en la tabla `servicios` solo almaceno el `id_instalador`.

Ahora lo que necesito es que del campo `id_gestiono`, que se almacena en la tabla `servicios`, obtenga de la tabla usuarios el nombre, que se encuentra en el campo `nombre_completo`.

Comment: sería util que nos enseñes la estructura de las tablas para ayudarte a hacer el select.

Comment: Necesitamos ver cómo tienes armadas tus tablas para ayudarte con los Joins

Comment: actualizadas las tablas en el texto de la pregunta, grcaias

Comment: Tu tabla de Servicios le falta un identificador del usuario, si bien tienes in ID de contrato, la pregunta es ¿Ese contrato a quien le pertenece? Si tu campo FK es el nombre del usuario no es una buena práctica. Mejor crea en tu tabla Servicios una FK para usuarios, por ejemplo id_cliente y referencialo a la tabla de usuarios al campo id_usuario

Comment: si lo tiene,ya lo inclui

Comment: Tienes un id_instalador y un id_gestiono, me queda claro que es el primero, ¿Pero el segundo que es? ¿Es el usuario?

Comment: Te falta un Join `inner join  usuarios as u on (tc.id_gestiono u. = id_usuario)`, luego simplemente referenciar a `u.nombre_completo`

Comment: Revisa la clave foránea id_gestiono hacia que tabla hace referencia. Si es a [usuarios] mediante id_usuario, bastaría con el INNER JOIN que te sugiere @PatricioMoracho, pero de no ser así. Necesitarías hacer el INNER JOIN hacia la tabla que esta faltando en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT 
tc.id_contrato,
tc.nombre_cliente,
tc.domicilio_instalacion,
tc.colonia,
tc.poblacion,
tc.telefono_local,
tc.telefono_cel_1,
tc.telefono_cel_2,
tc.telefono_cel_3,
tc.nombre_contacto,
tc.Comentario,
ti.nombre_completo as instalador,
hora_instalacion,
cita_confirmada,
u.nombre_completo
FROM bd_servicios tc
inner join bd_instaladores2  ti on tc.id_instalador = ti.id_instalador
inner join usuarios u on tc.id_gestiono = u.id_usuario
WHERE  fecha_instalacion = '$fecha_instalacion' 
ORDER BY instalador, hora_instalacion";
```

Tienes que hacer otro Join a la tabla de usuarios y ligar los IDs correspondientes y en el select traer el nombre del usuario con su respectivo acrónimo.

Saludos.